# Issue with Angular 2 AoT (ngc), Visual Studio 2015 and compileOnSave

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular2-aot

I'm following the Angular 2 AoT compilation guide here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community IDE.

When I run ngc, the ngfactory components are created in the `aot` directory (as defined in `tsconfig-aot.json`).

The Visual Studio IDE craps itself over all the ngfactory code. The bulk of the errors are related to the ngFactory code indifferently referencing private methods and properties, and employing incorrect call signatures...  e.g.

```
Build:Property _'viewContainerRef' is private and only accessible within class 'xyz.component';

Build:Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target, ngOnChanges().
```

Basically you cannot build until you add `"exclude": [ "aot" ]` to the `tsconfig.json` file.

This gets the IDE to chill out, mostly, but there is still one issue. The `main-aot.ts` file must import `app.component.ngfactory` from the `aot` folder (which has been excluded).

As is explained in the FAQs below, importing the excluded file is a big F-You and will cause Visual Studio to ignore the exclusion.

> Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler
>
> Why is a file in the exclude list still picked up by the compiler?
>
> tsconfig.json turns a folder into a “project”. Without specifying any
>   “exclude” or “files” entries, all files in the folder containing the
>   tsconfig.json and all its sub-directories are included in your
>   compilation.
>
> If you want to exclude some of the files use “exclude”, if you would
>   rather specify all the files instead of letting the compiler look them
>   up, use “files”.
>
> That was tsconfig.json automatic inclusion. There is a different
>   issue, which is module resolution. By module resolution, I mean the
>   compiler trying to understand what ns means in an import statement
>   like: import * ns from “mod”. To do so, the compiler needs the
>   definition of a module, this could be a .ts file for your own code, or
>   a .d.ts for an imported definition files. if the file was found, it
>   will be included regardless if it was excluded in the previous steps.
>
> So to exclude a file from the compilation, you need to exclude and all
>   all files that has an import or /// 
>   directives to it.

Basically, I also must `"exclude": [ "aot", "main-aot.ts" ]` to relieve all the errors.

The issue is that now, when I modify `main-aot.ts` file, the `compileOnSave: true` option in my `tsconfig.json` file doesn't have any effect. I assume this is because it has been excluded.

I rely on compileOnSave in order to generate all the B.S. that is needed to gulp, burp and fart the project into a deploy-able state.

I'm trying to find someone to advise on using Angular2 AoT, with compile on save, in Visual Studio 2015.

**EDIT 2/1/2017**: 
I've created a convoluted workaround for the time being.  I'm still hoping someone out there can provide a magic bullet that will make this less of a process.

I've taken advantage of the fact that VS2015 only seems to evaluate typescript configurations explicitly named `tsconfig.json`.

In `tsconfig.json`, I've excluded the `aot` folder and the `main-aot.ts` file.

I've created a `tsconfig-aot-ngc.json` file that mirrors the setup in the Angular2 AoT compilation guide.

I've created a third `tsconfig-aot-tsc.json` file that mirrors the `tsconfig.json` file, except instead of having any excludes, it explicitly includes `main-aot.ts` as such, `"files": [ "main-aot.ts"]`.

I've created a powershell script to glue this all together...

```
$root = "wwwroot";

$target ="wwwroot\aot\*";

$artifactsTs = "wwwroot\aot\*.ngfactory.ts";

$ngc = "../node_modules/.bin/ngc";
$tsConfigNgc = "./tsconfig-aot-ngc.json";

$tsc =  "tsc";
$tsConfigTsc = "./tsconfig-aot-tsc.json";

Write-Host "empty the aot folder...";
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -$target | Remove-Item -Recurse;

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = { Write-Host "ngc not found! run 'npm install -g ngc'" -ForegroundColor Red; };
Write-Host "ngc is compiling $tsConfigNgc...";
& $ngc -p $tsConfigNgc;

Write-Host "tsc is transpiling $tsConfigTsc...";
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = { Write-Host "tsc not found! run 'npm install -g typescript'" -ForegroundColor Red; };
& $tsc -p $tsConfigTsc;

Write-Host "deleting ts artifacts";
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.CommandNotFoundAction = { };
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $artifactsTs | Remove-Item -Recurse;
Write-Host 'done!';
```

What this does:

```
 1. delete everything from the aot folder. 
 2. run ngc to produce *.ngfactory.ts files and *.ngsummary.json files
 3. run tsc using an alternate tsconfig to produce *.ngfactory.js files.
 4. delete all *.ngfactory.ts files since they are not needed and only add confusion for VS2015.
```

I've also added `wwwroot\aot\*.ts` to my `.tfignore` file to prevent the files deleted in step 4 from being evaluated by source control.